# Prove that there is no simple group of order $216=2^{3}\cdot 3^{3}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory, simple-groups

> Prove that there is no simple group of order $216=2^{3}\cdot 3^{3}$.

I feel like I am supposed to use the Index Theorem here but when I use Sylow's Third Theorem I have that $n_{3}\in\{1,4\}$. I am not sure how to rule out the possibility that $n_{3}=4$. If I could then could use the fact that the unique Sylow 3-subgroup is normal in G to factor it and apply the Index Theorem. Any suggestions?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by factor and apply the index theorem.  If you can rule out $4$, you'd be done.  Not sure there's a way to do this though.

Comment: See: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2111420/every-group-of-order-216-contains-a-normal-subgroup-of-order-27-or-9

Comment: If $n_3 = 4$ then the conjugation action of $G$ on the Sylow $3$-subgroups induces a homomorphism $G \to S_4$, and if $G$ was simple that would have to be an injective map, which is clearly impossible.